# subset data by thousands of observations

Tags: sas, subset

I have two data sets:

Data set 1: This dataset has 2300 rows. The jobID is the same throughout the dataset, but the Hash is unique throughout the dataset

```
Hash          jobID
3456343454    1077
3453454       1077
43673         1077
.... and so on
```

Data set 2: This dataset has 5838918 rows. Different JobID values and different Hash values such as the following:
     Hash       jobID
    2223422     2
    233435      155
    2344322     1171
    ... and so on

What I am trying to attempt is to see whether any of the Hash values that is part of the first dataset also exists in the second dataset. Since it's over a thousand different unique Hash values in the first dataset, I cannot type each one of them to see whether it exists in the second dataset like the following:
    if hash in (value1 value2...etc), and to show the all Hash values that exist in Dataset 1 but not in dataset 2.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Also, the HASH is is Character ($32 format and informat), while JobID is numeric (Format:Best12./ Informat 12.)

Comment: Please, give us some more code and an example of how you want the final dataset to be.

Answer (score 2):

Use a SQL query to create the second list, you don't have to manually list the values.

```
proc sql;
create table in1_not2 as
select *
from table1 as a
where a.hash not in 
     (select b.hash from table2 as b);
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you could check with a simple merge.

Order the two datasets by Hash:

```
proc sort data=dataset1; by Hash; run;
proc sort data=dataset2; by Hash; run;
```

Check if the Hash is in both datasets:

```
data check;
merge dataset1 (in=a keep=Hash)
dataset2 (in=b keep=Hash);
by Hash;
if a and b;
run;
```

Note that all I'm doing is checking the hash, I'm not bringing any other variable to the final dataset.